# REST API: How to search for other attribute

Tags: api, node.js, rest, express

I use node.js as REST API.
There are following actions available:

1. /contacts, GET, finds all contacts
2. /contacts, POST, creats new contact
3. /contacts/:id, GET, shows or gets specifiy contact by it's id
4. /contacts/:id, PUT, updates a specific contact
5. /contacts/:id, DELETE, removes a specific contact

What would now be a logic Route for searching, quering after a user?
Should I put this to the 3. route or should I create an extra route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you will get a lot of different opinions on this question. Personally I would see "searching" as filtering on "all contacts" giving:

GET /contacts?filter=your_filter_statement

You probably already have filtering-parameters on GET /contacts to allow pagination that works well with the filter-statement.

EDIT:
Use this for parsing your querystring:

```
var url = require('url');
```

and in your handler ('request' being your nodejs http-request object):

```
var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url, true);
var filterStatement = parsedUrl.query.filter;
```

Comment: Hi, could you give me a sample code? I am not common with url queries in express/node

Comment: Ok, I put the filterStatement into the mongoose find expression. So how could I now filter with the url. I tried GET /contacts?filter=username but this doesn't filter at all and how can I define multiple filters?

Comment: As for the Mongoose/MongoDB find syntax I suggest you look in the Mongoose documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html and MongoDB querying: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. This is a discussion that I have had several times.

I don't think there is a clear answer, or maybe there is and I just don't know it or don't agree with it. I would say that you should add a new route: **/contacts/_search** performing an action on the contacts list, in this case a search. Clear and defined what you do then.

Comment: I think this would be a good approach for an extra search engine. But justquering would be more logic over the show action.

Comment: I was under the impression that was what you were intrested in doing. But lindstromhenrik had a nice approach as well

Answer (score -2):

`GET /contacts` finds all contacts. You want a subset of all contacts. What delimiter in a URI represents subsets? It's not "?"; that's non-hierarchical. The "/" character is used to delimit hierarchical path segments. So for a subset of contacts, try a URI like `/contacts/like/dave/` or `/contacts/by_name/susan/`.

This concept of subsetting data by path segments is for more than collections--it applies more broadly. Your whole site is a set, and each top-level path segment defines a subset of it: `http://yoursite.example/contacts` is a subset of `http://yoursite.example/`. It also applies more narrowly: `/contacts/:id` is a subset of `/contacts`, and `/contacts/:id/firstname` is a subset of `/contacts/:id`.